# Postgres initdb: How to set logging_collector=on in the generated postgressql.conf file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-initdb

The default postgresql.conf file created using initdb contains the following line

```
#logging_collector = off  # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
```

Is there anyway to force initdb itself to generate a file with

```
logging_collector = on
```

rather than set options on pg-ctl or edit the generated file.

Answer (score 1):

I keep all the changes in a separate file named `custom.conf`

Then after `initdb` ran, I copy the file to the data directory and append an `include` directive to `postgresql.conf`:

```
cp /path/to/dir/custom.conf $PGDATA
echo include = 'custom.conf' >> $PGDATA/postgresql.conf
```

These steps are easily scriptable, so no manual intervention required.

Alternatively you can skip the copy step and include the config file directly from the central directory. Or you could use `include_dir` to include the whole directory where your custom config file is stored.

This has the added benefit (in my opinion) that I have all customizations in a single file. I don't need to go through `postgresql.conf` to find settings that are changed from the default.

Comment: That's the direction I was going in too.. I just  wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do it like that.

But you can modify the file `postgresql.conf.sample` in the “share” directory of the PostgreSQL installation, which is used as the blueprint for `postgresql.conf` during `initdb`.

Comment: Damn, and the Thanks. Unfortunately modifying the template has the same challanges as modifying the file itself. I am creating a windows container, so I download the Installation media as part of myDockerfile, so I don't win anything by modifying the file before I invoke initdb.

Comment: You can certainly modify an installed file in your dockerfile, right?